# div position fixed on the scroll, start before the top of the page

Tags: jquery, css, html, scroll

How can I get the "Sidebar" to be fixed position when it reaches the "Fixed header" and not the page's top?

**[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VtPcm/705/)**

```
$(function() {
    var top = $('#sidebar').offset().top - parseFloat($('#sidebar').css('marginTop').replace(/auto/, 0));
    var footTop = $('#footer').offset().top - parseFloat($('#footer').css('marginTop').replace(/auto/, 0));

    var maxY = footTop - $('#sidebar').outerHeight();

    $(window).scroll(function(evt) {
        var y = $(this).scrollTop();
        if (y > top) {
            if (y < maxY) {
                $('#sidebar').addClass('fixed').removeAttr('style');
            } else {
                $('#sidebar').removeClass('fixed').css({
                    position: 'absolute',
                    top: (maxY - top) + 'px'
                });
            }
        } else {
            $('#sidebar').removeClass('fixed');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: You'd just need to do something like `y > (top - $('#fixedHeader').height())`

Comment: ok, where exactly should I write it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line:

```
if (y > top) {
```

assuming your fixed header has no padding (otherwise you'll have to take that into account as well) you could change to this

```
if (y >= top - $('#fixedHeader').height()) {
```

remove `top:0px;` from your sidebar css, and add the expected height for for your fixed header (currently you've given it a height of 40px), so

```
#sidebar.fixed {
  position: fixed;
  top: 40px;
}
```

I've also removed padding from your `#fixedHeader`, as you didn't specify what it was/if you even wanted any. If you did want padding, as mentioned above, you'll have to add that into your calculation as well.

http://jsfiddle.net/VtPcm/706/